# node.js: passing list from node js code to hbs html page not always work(sometimes gives me outputs and somtimes empty and no outputs)

Tags: node.js, express, arraylist, handlebars.js

my goal is so simple , just passing this variables and a list from my node.js code to my html .hbs  file using:

```js
res.render('justreadthefentemp', {"personList": personList,thewinrnicknm,thewinrid,thegmsts,gmendhtml,cllr,gmdate});
```

and every thing worked with no errors but still there  are a problem in the list part my code can push the data successfully

```js
personList.push(person);
```

and i can checking that with the console.log code

```js
console.log('her the lenght of the list',personList.length);
```

and i can seeing the outputs on my webpage put not all the time some time i see the whole variables and the list outputs on my html  web page and some times i only see the variables but the list part are empty but i still can seeing the console.log output saying there are a data exist in my list 
but on my html page there are no data from the list output

> my whole node.js code:

```js
app.get('/theviewerpage/:thgmhshid([0-9]{1,9})', function (req, res, next) {

    var tgmhashpage = req.params.thgmhshid;
    var personList = [];
    var thegmsts;
    var gmendhtml;
    var returnflsortrue;
    var cllr;
    var uso;
    var thewinrnicknm;
    var thewinrid;
    var thegmsts;

    if (req.user === undefined) {
        return res.redirect('/theviewerpageforpublic/' + tgmhashpage + '');
    } else {
        uso = req.user.id;
        console.log('usohoooo');
    }

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM moves_viewer_list WHERE Gamehash = '" + tgmhashpage + "' ORDER BY `moves_viewer_list`.`gamestartdate` ASC ", function (err, rows, result) {
        console.log('oh mysql');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            gmdate = datetime.create(rows[i].gamestartdate).format('Y/m/d H:M:S');

            thewinrnicknm = rows[i].whowin;
            thewinrid = rows[i].whowinid;
            thegmsts = rows[i].gameending;
        }

        console.log('yes her ???');
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM moves_viewer WHERE gamehash = '" + tgmhashpage + "' ORDER BY `moves_viewer`.`movedate` ASC ", function (err, rows, result) {
            console.log('duhhhh');
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                console.log("hghghgh");

                var person = {
                    'The_Move': rows[i].TheMoveString,
                    'the_whomov': whomov,
                    'the_i': i,
                    'themovedate': "This Move Date:" + datetime.create(rows[i].movedate).format('Y/m/d H:M:S')
                }
                personList.push(person);
                console.log('her the lenght of the list', personList.length);
            }
        })

        res.render('justreadthefentemp', {
            "personList": personList,
            thewinrnicknm,
            thewinrid,
            thegmsts,
            gmendhtml,
            cllr,
            gmdate
        });

    })

});
```

and for the other variables i just writing this simple line in anywhere in the html code and it's works all the time and with no problems

```
{{thewinrid}} 
{{thewinrnicknm}}
//etc..
```

so what's the wrong i don't know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is below

```js
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM moves_viewer WHERE gamehash = '" + tgmhashpage + "' ORDER BY `moves_viewer`.`movedate` ASC ", function (err, rows, result) {
            console.log('duhhhh');
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                console.log("hghghgh");

                var person = {
                    'The_Move': rows[i].TheMoveString,
                    'the_whomov': whomov,
                    'the_i': i,
                    'themovedate': "This Move Date:" + datetime.create(rows[i].movedate).format('Y/m/d H:M:S')
                }
                personList.push(person);
                console.log('her the lenght of the list', personList.length);
            }
        })

        res.render('justreadthefentemp', {
            "personList": personList,
            thewinrnicknm,
            thewinrid,
            thegmsts,
            gmendhtml,
            cllr,
            gmdate
        });

    })

});
```

So when you call `connection.query`, it results is an `async` operation and the callback function is called when the results are ready. But instead of render the the template in the callback, you render it immediately after calling the `connection.query`

Now when the render call happens the `personList` list may not be completely populated. And hence the delta you see in your results. You need to understand that `node.js` is basically asynchronous, so you need to be aware of how and where to use the data. Once you update the call like below

```js
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM moves_viewer WHERE gamehash = '" + tgmhashpage + "' ORDER BY `moves_viewer`.`movedate` ASC ", function (err, rows, result) {
            console.log('duhhhh');
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                console.log("hghghgh");

                var person = {
                    'The_Move': rows[i].TheMoveString,
                    'the_whomov': whomov,
                    'the_i': i,
                    'themovedate': "This Move Date:" + datetime.create(rows[i].movedate).format('Y/m/d H:M:S')
                }
                personList.push(person);
                console.log('her the lenght of the list', personList.length);
            }

            res.render('justreadthefentemp', {
                "personList": personList,
                thewinrnicknm,
                thewinrid,
                thegmsts,
                gmendhtml,
                cllr,
                gmdate
            });
        })
```

This makes sure that render is done after the variable `personList` is completely populated with the data

Answer (score 0):

Put that res.render inside the callback, after for loop

Comment: can you explaining why this problem happen ?

Comment: When you are fetching data from the database, thats an asynchronous task. So what JS does is move on to next line and does not wait for that ASYNCHRONOUS TASK. After that your personList is empty and you just render it but if you put that in that callback it will wait for that asynchronous task and after that task is complete it will render the file.
You should learn about asynchronous execution in javascript